# TFS "view history" grayed out

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

TFS **View History** and **Compare** are grayed out. I also can't "check out" - it seems to  be automatic when saving a file. So perhaps both are related. I *did* make a change, so it's not that there are no changes.

I'm a newbie to TFS. I've just installed it,..., added a test project to source control. And am trying to see what I can do with it. So don't discount any obvious answers.

I can see the collection's history which just shows me one item - "created team project..." but the **View History** and **Compare** of the folders are grayed out.

Comment: Stupid question, but did you checked sth *in* before you try to check sth out?

Comment: @downvoter Care to explain why? A newbie question? For sure. I thought those were accepted on SO.

Comment: @lokusking by `sth` do you mean TFS? If yes - I did connect to the TSH server. More than that I don't know. As far as I understand everything is being saved because I can see it in source control explorer. As I've said - I'm new to this, so if I misunderstood you please let me know.

Comment: After you initially added a project in TFS you have to Check everything in. There is no such thing like an Auto-Commit to your local operations. TFS is a complex theme, so i highly recommend some Tutorials

Comment: @lokusking Thanks you very much. You can convert your comment into an answer. The moment you told me `There is no such thing like an Auto-Commit` I knew what to look for!  (About tutorials - I did do some reading before starting and before posting the question. But sometimes a little help is still needed. That's where you come in. Thanks a lot!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you initially added a project in TFS you have to Check everything in. There is no such thing like an Auto-Commit to your local operations. TFS is a complex theme, so i highly recommend some Tutorials.

Answered as you suggested :)